# How to access a file in vars(obj) in python?

Tags: python, object, variables

vars(obj) returns the following:

```
'**_fields_**': [('rlcAmUlConfig', <class 'l2types.struct_L2_DB_RLC_AM_UL_Config'>), ('rlcAmDlConfig', <class 'l2types.struct_L2_DB_RLC_AM_DL_Config'>)], 
'rlcAmDlConfig': <Field type=struct_L2_DB_RLC_AM_DL_Config, ofs=20, size=12>, 
'**__slots__**': ['rlcAmUlConfig', 'rlcAmDlConfig'], 'rlcAmUlConfig': <Field type=struct_L2_DB_RLC_AM_UL_Config, ofs=0, size=20>, 
'**__dict__**': <attribute '__dict__' of 'struct_L2_DB_RLC_AM_Config' objects>, 
'**__weakref__**': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'struct_L2_DB_RLC_AM_Config' objects>, 
'**__doc__**': None}
```

How can I access 
`<Field type=struct_L2_DB_RLC_AM_DL_Config, ofs=20, size=12>` through obj?

How can i access all the fields in the vars obj and print the ofs and size properties?

I can access some properties via `obj.__modules__. obj.__fields__`.

Comment: It's in builtin vars() function in python

Comment: Can you make it clear what sort of object you're working with? This looks like a *class's* attributes (though it should be wrapped in a `mappingproxy`, not a raw `__dict__`, and the `__slots__` should be incompatible with the class level `Field` declarations in a `dataclass`), not that of an object. `vars` is just returning a `dict`-like thing, so you could just use regular `dict` lookups, but I feel like you're omitting some crucial context necessary to provide a good answer.